# How to get percentage of total yearly sales for several years in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, data-science

Probably my question is not self-explanatory, and for that reason I'm using a dummy table to explain what my problem is  and what I would like to get.
I have a table like following

```
|channel|year|revenue|
 online  2011  10
reseller 2011  40
online   2012  15
reseller 2012  45
online   2013  28
reseller 2013  28
```

I visualized this data in a clustered bar chart (axis= year, legend=channel, and value= revenue) and it shows me numbers of yearly revenue contributed by different channel, for example in 2011, online 10 and reseller 40.

But I would like to show it  as percentages of total sales for 2011 (for example, 2011 online 20% & reseller 80%, for 2012 online 25% & reseller 75%, for 2012 online 50% & reseller 50%.

How it can be achieved?
probably I need to get a new measure but don't know the DAX. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply calculation:

```
YourRevenueMeasure = 
SUM('YourTable'[Revenue])

PercentageOfSales = 
DIVIDE( [YourRevenueMeasure],
 calculate( [YourRevenueMeasure], FILTER(ALL('YourTable'), 'YourTable'[Year] = SELECTEDVALUE('YourTable'[Year])))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** create this below Measure-

```
revenue_ = 
var total_ = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[revenue]),
    ALLEXCEPT(
        your_table_name,
        your_table_name[year]
    )
)

RETURN MIN(your_table_name[revenue])/total_
```

**Now** change the measure type as **%** and use it in the **Values** field in Clustered Bar Chart.